# AJAX not firing before Callback

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback, window.location

I'm attempting to run an AJAX query and insert the results into a local database before moving onto a new window.location. However, the success function to insert the results does not run. Instead the callback function causes the new page to load.  If I comment out the if (callback {callback();} then the AJAX completes the inserts, but the window.location code is obviously not called. The callback function seems to get called before the AJAX success function is completed. How do I get the AJAX success to insert the results before moving on? Here's the code I'm using:

```
<script>
        var db = window.openDatabase("MantisMobileDB1", "", "MantisMobileDB", 1024 * 1000);
function CreateDB() {
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Routes(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, routeID TEXT, customerID TEXT, stopSeq TEXT, driverID TEXT)', []);
    });
}
function insertRoute(routeID, customerID, stopSeq, driverID) {
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Routes (routeID, customerID, stopSeq, driverID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', [routeID, customerID, stopSeq, driverID], CountReturns);
    });
}

        function loadInitialRouteList(callback) {
            var dataObject = {
                postDesignator: 'routes'
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://url.php',
                data: dataObject,
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'post',
                success: function (Result) {
                    for (var i = 0, len = Result.records.length; i < len; ++i) {
                        var route = Result.records[i].record;
                        insertRoute(route.routeID, null, null, null);
                    }
                    if (callback) { callback(); }
                }
            });

        }

    if (localStorage.getItem('exitsatus') === null) {
        CreateDB();
        loadInitialRouteList(function () { window.location = 'Application.html'; }); 
    }
    else {
        window.location = localStorage.getItem('exitsatus');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your code looks weird. I'm missing the `)` for `db.transaction()`.

Comment: Is `tx.executeSql` asynchronous?

Comment: Thanks. Copied it incorrectly.  I fixed the error and added the insertRoute function.

Comment: Paste that code in here: http://jsfiddle.net/ hit the "Tidyup" and "JSHint" buttons to see what we see.

Comment: I sincerely hope you do not have that SQL code in your production code in any way, shape or form as it is totally open to a SQL injection attack - for instance, someone could delete your database entirely.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss it's local storage, it doesn't matter so much.

Comment: You're sure it's not just hitting the else part on the last conditional, as you're not setting the localStorage item anywhere, and if you did'nt clear your browsers localStorage, the item would still be there, making the if / else fail, redirecting right away.

Comment: Yes; The inserts work if I comment out if (callback) {callback();} line, but then of course the page doesn't move to the Application. I believe it has to do with the callback attempting to fire before the AJAX is complete

Comment: You could just use the built in promise, and not a callback function, like [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mBa4F/2/)

Comment: Also, isn't Web SQL's db.transaction asyncronous, so you would probably redirect before the SQL statements have completed ?

Comment: Yea. That's got to be the issue.

Comment: @adeneo Getting cannot call method done of undefined when I try and using the built in promise

Comment: works for me [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mBa4F/3/) (I had to call always(), as the ajax fails when url.php does'nt exist) ?